# Displaying AngularFireList on html after getting data

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

Im trying to display AngularFireList<> on html.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {AngularFireDatabase,AngularFireList} from 'angularfire2/database';



@Component({
  selector: 'page-profile',
  templateUrl: 'profile.html'
})

export class ProfilePage {
  profileData: AngularFireList<any>


  constructor(private fire:AngularFireAuth,private db :AngularFireDatabase,public navCtrl: NavController) {

    this.fire.authState.subscribe(auth => {
    // subscribe to the observable
    this.profileData = this.db.list<profileData>(`profile/${auth.uid}`).valueChanges().subscribe(p =>{

console.log(p);

    });


  });



  }

}
```

I can get data with this code  but i guess i cant make it equal to profileData so i cant display it on screen.

```
<ul *ngFor="let profile of profileData | async">
                                      <li> {{ profile.username}}:{{ profile.msgnumber}} </li>
                                    </ul>
```

Comment: do you see any errors on console?

Comment: no just console.log

Comment: can you post what is inside console.log

Comment: db structure is like profile - authid- username,msgnumber... maybe it can be because of authid ?

Comment: can you post the json what you see in the console.log

Comment: (3) [0, 0, "dsfdsfdssfd"]
0
:
0
1
:
0
2
:
"dsfdsfdssfd"
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: still its not the correct data . add this code and see what is printed in console.  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.profileData));

Comment: [0,0,"dsfdsfdssfd"]       by the way  after removing subscribe() part from code  console.log(profileData) is not working. still using console.log(p) with subscribe

Comment: it seems your data is not an array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157241/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-yunus-emre-guney-student).

Comment: https://image.prntscr.com/image/to9S7rsZQ-qdsfyHpapW7A.png

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

No need to subscribe to valueChanges().
See [angularfire2 docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be,

```
this.profileData = this.db.list<profileData>(`profile/${auth.uid}`).valueChanges();
```

Comment: thanks i changed it but still i cant display in on page(html)

Comment: Does it help if you change type of profileData to Observable<any[]> instead of AngularFireList<any>?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for the benefit of future users who encounter such error,this should work

```
this.profileDataRef = this.db.list(`profile/${auth.uid}`);      
    this.profileData = this.profileDataRef.valueChanges();
```

HTML TEMPLATE

```
<ul *ngFor="let profile of profileData | async">
       <li> {{ profile.username}}:{{ profile.msgnumber}} </li>
    </ul>
```